# Why is the time complexity of a Dijkstra Algorithm using matrix representation better than a list representation for dense graph

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dijkstra

I have been looking up on the internet but so far, I have not found a closure to my question.

For Dijkstra Algorithm using matrix representation, the time complexity is O(V^2).

But for list representation, the time complexity is O((V+E)Log(V)).

However, when I plot the graph for various vertices and edge density, I have found out that the matrix representation is actually better for denser graph. **But why ? Because theoretically speaking should O(V^2) be doing worst.
**

```py
def generateRandomGraph(self, vertices, chancesToSpawnEdge = 0.5, printLog = True):
        self.edges = 0
        self.vertices = vertices
        self.matrix = [[float('inf') for i in range(vertices)] for j in range(vertices)] # adjacency matrix
        self.adj_list = {}
        self.type = "ADJ_MATRIX"
        for i in range(vertices):
            for j in range(vertices):

                if random.choices([0, 1], weights=[(1-chancesToSpawnEdge), chancesToSpawnEdge])[0]:
                    if i != j:
                        self.matrix[i][j] = random.randint(1, 100)
                        self.edges += 1
                    else:
                        self.matrix[i][j] = 0

        # Print the number of vertices and edges
        if printLog:
            print("Vertices:", self.vertices)
            print("Edges:", self.edges)
            print("Edge Density:", round(self.calculate_edge_density(),5))

def dijkstraM(self, source, printLog = True):
        # Uses an array as priority queue

        numOfVertex = 0
        numOfEdges = 0
        
        d = [float('inf') for i in range(self.vertices)]
        pi = [float('inf') for i in range(self.vertices)] # Predecessor so pi[i] = j means j is the predecessor of i
        s = [False for i in range(self.vertices)] # If S[i] = True, then the vertex i is in the set S, else not
        pq = [float('inf') for i in range(self.vertices)]

        s[source] = True
        d[source] = 0
        pq[source] = 0

    
        # While the priority queue is not empty equivalent
        while True:
            u = self.__extractCheapest__(pq)

            # If the priority queue is empty, then break 
            # Means that all the vertices have been added to the set S
            if u == -1:
                break

            s[u] = True # Add the vertex u to the set S

            numOfVertex += 1
            
            for v in range(self.vertices): #(O(|V|) because we are iterating through all the vertices)
                numOfEdges += 1

                # Check if the edge u->v exists and if v is not in the set S 
                # And if the distance from source to v is greater than the distance from source to u + the weight of the edge u->v
                if self.matrix[u][v] != 0 and s[v] == False and ((d[u] + self.matrix[u][v]) < d[v]):

                    # Update the distance from source to v
                    d[v] = d[u] + self.matrix[u][v]
                    # Update the predecessor of v
                    pi[v] = u
                    # Update the priority queue (O(1)) because we are inserting
                    pq[v] = d[v]
                    

    def dijkstraL(self, source, printLog = True):
        # Uses minimizing heap as priority queue
        
        numOfVertex = 0
        numOfEdges = 0
        
        d = [float('inf') for i in range(self.vertices)]
        pi = [float('inf') for i in range(self.vertices)] # Predecessor so pi[i] = j means j is the predecessor of i
        s = [False for i in range(self.vertices)] # If S[i] = True, then the vertex i is in the set S, else not

        ########### IMPLEMENTATION IS ROUGHLY THE SAME AS THE MATRIX IMPLMENTATION ###########
        # Just that the extraction Cheapest and the update priority queue is different

        s[source] = True
        d[source] = 0

        pq = PriorityQueue()
        pq.insert((0, source)) # Insert the vertex, distance O(lg|v|)  because heappq looks sees the first elemnt in the tuple as the priority

        # Only need to fixHeap everytime we insert instead of heapifying it since we are only one element at a time
        while not pq.is_empty(): # While the priority queue is not empty equivalent
         
            dist, u = self.__extractCheapestPQ__(pq) # Extract the cheapest vertex from the priority queue (O(1))

            s[u] = True # Add the vertex u to the set S

            numOfVertex += 1

            for v in self.adj_list[u]: # (O(|E|) because we are iterating through all the edges connected to u)
                numOfEdges += 1

                # Check if v is not in the set S
                # And if the distance from source to v is greater than the distance from source to u + the weight of the edge u->v
                if s[v[0]] == False and ((dist + v[1]) < d[v[0]]):
                    # Update the distance from source to v
                    d[v[0]] = dist + v[1]
                    # Update the predecessor of v
                    pi[v[0]] = u
                    # Update the priority queue (O(lg|v|)) because we are inserting
                    pq.insert((d[v[0]], v[0]))


    def __extractCheapestPQ__(self, pq):

        eC = pq.remove()

        return eC
    
    def __extractCheapest__(self, pq):
        min = float('inf')
        u = 0

        # print("PQ" , pq) 

        # Find the minimum in the priority queue O(|V|))
        for i in range(self.vertices):
            if pq[i] < min:
                min = pq[i]
                u = i

        # Remove the minimum from the priority queue because it is now in the set S
        pq[u] = float('inf')

        # If the minimum is still infinity, then the priority queue is empty
        if min == float('inf'):
            return -1

        return u
```

This are the graph I generated

[image: 6000 Vertices]
[image: 2000 Vertices]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost answered your own question by providing the time complexities:

- Matrix: O(²)
- List: O((+)log)

Only the complexity of the adjacency list algorithm depends on the number of edges, and so it is expected that in your statistics you find that the first algorithm doesn't show much difference when increasing the number of edges, while for the second algorithm this has an effect.

Be aware that for the maximum edge density, we have  = O(²), which makes the second complexity O(²log), which is not O(²)!

Whether or not for a given value of  there are densities for which the matrix algorithm runs *faster* than the other algorithm, cannot be seen from the complexities alone -- this depends on the constants and coefficients that the implementation and architecture provide, but we can be confident that when  is *great enough*, there is a density above which the matrix algorithm will run faster.

Comment: ヾ(・ω・*) I have one more question. Why is it that the time taken for my matrix representation time complexity  decrease as the edge density increases ?  One answer I could think of is that by having more path, there is higher chance of finding shorter path.

Comment: I have ran multiple tests for the same algorithm with matrix represntaion. All of them travel the same number of vertices and edges but a higher edge density incur a lower run time.

Comment: Not sure, but here is an idea: the comparison with floats might be more costly than with (small) integers. With a high density, `pq` will soon be filled with all integers, reducing the work of `__extractCheapest__` to integer-only operations.